# as3: better way to render many objects with png-sequences?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, movieclip

so I'm working on a game for mobile using AirForAndroid as3. In the game I need to have a lot of enemies at once on the screen (up to 15 would do I assume). These enemies are atm movieclips and contain various movieclips within, such as shapes that work as hitareas which are vital to the games functionality. The enemy-movieclip also contains a png sequence (a walk loop). Right now this seems to be veeeery unefficient for mobile devices, since 4 or 5 enemies at once already makes the game extremely slow on my galaxyS3.

So the question is, is there a diffrent approach to "render" the enemies, to make the display process less "expensive" ... I can't really get around the png sequence itself, which will span to maybe 200 pics combined, walk, run, fight animations and so on. If anybody has an idea or knows a trick or can put me towards a better solution, that would be awesome.

thanks for reading,
ANB_Seth

Comment: You should have a single set of PNGs for all the enemies, in case they are one type.

Comment: you might consider using starling... it will GPU accelerate your graphics http://gamua.com/starling/

Answer (score 2):

1. The `MovieClip` is very expensive (memory consumption and CPU/GPU performance) object. Especially on mobile devices. I recommend you to give up using `MovieClips` at all.
2. There is standard game-dev technique to make animation: `Spritesheet animation`.

Some links: [Tutorial](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=140), [Performance comparison: MovieClip vs Spritesheet](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/fast-rendering-in-air-cached-spritesheets), [Descriptions of the main idea and implementation](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-spritesheet-animation--gamedev-13099)

Comment: It cannot be stressed enough just how poor `MovieClip` is for applications that require any degree of efficient performance, especially on mobile to any degree.